# Identifying the dual group of a locally compact abelian group with the spectrum of $ {L^{1}}(G) $.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-groups, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Folland stated the following theorem in his book *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis* on Page 88.

> The dual group of a locally compact abelian group can be identified with the spectrum of $ {L^{1}}(G) $.

It came without a proof, so could anyone kindly provide me with some comments on my attempt below?

*Proof*: Let $ G $ be a locally compact abelian group and $ \widehat{G} $ the dual group of $ G $, i.e., $ \widehat{G} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{T}) $, where $ \mathbb{T} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1 \} $. The spectrum of $ {L^{1}}(G) $, denoted by $ \text{Spec}({L^{1}}(G)) $, is defined as
$$
\text{Spec}({L^{1}}(G))
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\{
F \in {L^{1}}(G)^{\star} \mid
F \not\equiv 0 ~ \text{and} ~ F(f * g) = F(f) \cdot F(g)
\},
$$
where $ * $ denotes convolution. In other words, $ \text{Spec}({L^{1}}(G)) $ is the set of all non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $ {L^{1}}(G) $.

To show that $ \widehat{G} $ can be identified with $ \text{Spec}({L^{1}}(G)) $, we need to construct a $ 1 $-$ 1 $ correspondence $ \widehat{G} \to \text{Spec}({L^{1}}(G)) $. Define such a correspondence as follows. Every $ \beta \in \widehat{G} $ defines a multiplicative linear functional $ \hat{\beta} $ on $ {L^{1}}(G) $ by
$$
\forall f \in {L^{1}}(G): \quad
\hat{\beta}(f)
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\int_{G} f(g) \beta(g) ~ \mathrm{d}{g}. \quad \blacksquare
$$

**Question:** Did I define the $ 1 $-$ 1 $ correspondence correctly?

Comment: Dear user147972, if you’re truly satisfied with a particular response to your question, please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside it. This awards the owner of the response with points for the hard work that he/she has done.

Answer (score 6):

By $-g$ I am assuming you mean $g^{-1}$. Let $G$ is a locally compact group, $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $\rho:G\rightarrow \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{H})$ is a (unitary) representation. Traditionally when one lifts $\rho$ to a representation $\tilde{\rho}:L^1(G)\rightarrow B(H)$, the standard definition is

$$\tilde{\rho}(f) = \int_G f(g)\rho(g)\,dg.$$

This definition is understood weakly. Moreover can be motivated somewhat easily from the setting of finite groups. In your case, $\rho$ is an element of the dual group $\widehat{G}$, $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{H}) = \mathbb{T}$ since the only unitary elements on $\mathbb{C}$ are toroidal elements. It is not incorrect to consider $\rho(g^{-1})$ instead of $\rho(g)$ in the integral but traditionally we do not. Philosophically the reason is probably to keep expressions as simple as possible without complicating them unnecessarily.

This is definitely a homomorphism on $L^1(G)$ since

\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{\rho}(f_1\ast f_2) &=& \int_G (f_1\ast f_2)(g)\rho(g)\,dg \\
&=& \int_G \left(\int_G f_1(g')f_2(g'^{-1}g)\,dg'\right)\rho(g)\,dg \\
&=& \int_G \int_G f_1(g')f_2(g'^{-1}g)\,dg'\rho(g')\rho(g'^{-1}g)\,dg \\
&\stackrel{\text{Fubini}}{=}& \int_G f_1(g')\rho(g')\int_G f_2(g'^{-1}g)\rho(g'^{-1}g)\,dg\,dg' \\
&\stackrel{\text{left invariance}}{=}& \int_G f_1(g')\rho(g')\,dg'\int_Gf_2(g)\rho(g)\,dg\\
&=& \tilde{\rho}(f_1)\tilde{\rho}(f_2).
\end{eqnarray}

Note that you have *not* shown one-to-one correspondence with this relation. You have merely shown that every (continuous) character gives rise to an element in $\Delta(L^1(G))$ (the spectrum of $L^1(G)$).

To show the other direction takes much more work. Consider a multiplicative linear functional $\Phi$ on $L^1(G)$, i.e. an element of $\Delta(L^1(G))$. Then by the Riesz representation theorem, $\Phi$ is given by an integral against some $\phi\in L^{\infty}(G)$, i.e.

$$\Phi(f) = \int_G \phi(g)f(g)\,dg.$$

However since $\Phi$ is multiplicative and nonzero, there is $f_1\in L^1(G)$ so that $\Phi(f_1)\neq 0$ and for all $f_2\in L^1(G)$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\Phi(f_1\ast f_2) &=& \Phi(f_1)\Phi(f_2) \\
&=& \int_G \Phi(f_1)\phi(g)f_2(g)\,dg. \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Furthermore,

\begin{eqnarray}
\Phi(f_1\ast f_2) &=& \int_G \phi(g')(f_1\ast f_2)(g')\,dg' \\
&=& \int_G \phi(g')\left(\int_G f_1(g^{-1}g')f_2(g)\,dg\right)\,dg' \\
&\stackrel{\text{Fubini}}{=}&\int_G\left(\int_G\phi(g')f_1(g^{-1}g')\,dg'\right)f_2(g)\,dg \\
&=& \int_G \Phi(L_gf_1)f_2(g)\,dg, \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

where $L_gf_1(g') = f_1(g^{-1}g')$. Note the appearance of the inverse. (I loathe Folland's choice for convolution as I think it makes things a little bit more complicated than they need to be.) $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal for all $f_2\in L^1(G)$ and so we must conclude that

$$\phi(g)\Phi(f_1)=\Phi(L_gf_1).\tag{3}$$

$\Phi$ is a continuous linear functional and so if $g_{\lambda}$ is a net converging to $g$, then $\Phi(L_{g_{\lambda}}f_1)\rightarrow \Phi(L_gf_1)$. Hence $\phi$ agrees almost everywhere with a continuous function and so we may as well assume $\phi$ is continuous.

All that is left to see is that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and that $|\phi(g)| = 1$ for all $g\in G$. From the above equality, we know that

\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(gg')\Phi(f_1) &=& \Phi(L_{gg'}f_1) \\
&=& \Phi(L_{g'}L_gf_1) \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=}& \phi(g')\Phi(L_gf_1) \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=}& \phi(g')\phi(g)\Phi(f_1)
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\Phi(f_1)$ is nonzero by our above hypothesis, we must conclude that $\phi(gg') = \phi(g')\phi(g)$. However $\phi(g)$ is just a number so in fact $\phi(gg') = \phi(g)\phi(g')$ and therefore $\phi$ is a homomorphism onto $\mathbb{C}$.

To see that $|\phi(g)|= 1$, first note that if $|\phi(g)|\le 1$ for all $g$, then $|\phi(g^{-1})|\le 1$ as well. However this is only possible if $|\phi(g)=1$. So if we can show that $|\phi(g)|=1$, we would be done. This is easily achieved by noting that $\phi(g^n)  = \phi(g)^n$. Since $\phi\in L^{\infty}(G)$, $\phi$ must be bounded but the only way for this to happen is if $|\phi(g)|\le 1$ since otherwise $\phi(g^n)$ would diverge to infinity. Thus every multiplicative linear functional on $L^1(G)$, i.e. every element of $\Delta(L^1(G))$, corresponds to a character. Therefore there is a one-to-one correspondence between the dual group and $\Delta(L^1(G))$.

Comment: Thank you.According to your definition How is proved One-to-one correspondence?

Comment: I have edited my post to include more information.

Comment: wow, I was very happy to see your post. thank you. I read this and  if I had any questions I ask of you . Again, thank you

Comment: You're very welcome! Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Excellent . good  Luck.